# Metric Tensor and Electromagnetic Field Tensor from a Single Asymmetric 2-Tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity

Are there examples in the literature, where one starts with an asymmetric tensor, and then decomposes it into its symmetric part, identifying it as the metric, and antisymmetric part, somehow associating that with the electromagnetic field tensor?

Physically, they are quite different, and the electromagnetic tensor is exact 2-form (antisymmetric cotensor), $F=dA$ (where $F$ is the electromagnetic field 2-form and $A$ is the electromagnetic potential 1-form) rather than a general 2-form, so perhaps a tall order, but I wonder how far someone has taken the idea.

Comment: I believe Einstein himself tried to do this but had his hopes dashed: https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.92.1567

Comment: The problem with deriving e.g. the EFEs & Maxwell from $X_{ab}:=g_{ab}+CF_{ab}$, where the constant $C$ prevents dimensional inconsistency, is the radically different forms of these PDEs, with only the latter set linear. So it's not obvious they fall out of the same elegant equation in $X$. Historically, we've tried [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory).

Comment: @ConnorBehan That looks like (the beginning of) an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: the other thing to note is that not only are the field equations, quite different, the influence on matter is quite diffferent.  solving $m{\ddot x}^{a} = F^{ab}j_{b}$ involves $F_{ab}$ in a very different way than solving the geodesic equations involves $g_{ab}$

Comment: This is different from what you asked, but in [1305.6961](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6961) and [1406.1226](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1226) a natural tensor (denoted $\langle A\otimes B\rangle$) is defined whose symmetric part is the energy-momentum tensor, and whose anti-symmetric part is the dual of the electromagnetic field tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following some of the comments, i found what I think is a good 2-part review article:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2004-2

https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2014-5

This covers a number of attempts to unify gravity and electromagnetism, including asymmetric metrics. As some comments mention, it didn’t lead to much useful physically, although it did develop interesting mathematics.